# Jumping to Method directly while debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When debugging the Code, How to jump directly to Implementation method. Is there any Settings?

Example :- If I press <kbd>F11</kbd> it will navigate to interface first then to the Implementation Method while debugging.

Is there any shortcut key or Settings?

Answer (score 0):

You need to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> to achieve this. As an alternative you can right click on the method and select "Go to Implementation" option from context menu. Actually in debug mode, navigating to interface doesn't make any sense and it should go to the implementation by pressing <kbd>F11</kbd> which stands for Step Into operation. Otherwise you can use the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> combination keys. With that being said, if you still have some difficulty to go to the implementation method, so most likely that method is not accessible to you and you can just see it's declaration interface.